# nginx proxy_pass to external url fail

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'd like to config nginx to proxy_pass my domain *xyz.abc.com to external url such as google.com/...The idea is same as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345233/nginx-proxy-pass-to-external-url). But it constantly show error below:

```
 [error] 12725#12725: *1530410 no resolver defined to resolve google.com, client: 27.64.99.7, server: ~^(?<name>\w+)\.xyz\.abc\.com$, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "ivy1.xyz.abc.com", referrer: "http://ivy1.xyz.abc.com/"
```

Here is my config

```
 server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>\w+)\.xyz\.abc\.com$;
    location / {

      proxy_pass https://google.com/$name$request_uri;
      proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Is the something wrong in my configuration? I'm using nginx 1.11.6

Comment: You need to define a `resolver`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard advice,I set resolver in location context which solved my issue.

```
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  resolver_timeout 10s;
```