# Nginx route my localhost port requests to external url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I was trying to route my localhost:8585 requests to some external url, say https://someExternalSite.xyz. Such that i can access the external site using localhost port url in my app.

i.e if i **curl localhost:8585**, it should actually return the output of **curl https://someExternalSite.xyz**

I have tried this configuration but not working

```
server {
    listen 8585;
    listen [::]:8585;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
                proxy_pass https://someExternalSite.xyz/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

Need some help

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345233/nginx-proxy-pass-to-external-url

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that was the different scenario. That was proxy passing request of example1.com to example2.com. But i was trying to proxy localhost:8585 to an external url